# Unable to connect to server pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pgadmin

I installed PostgreSQL on my Ubuntu virtual machine (ip: 192.168.195.95). Now, I'm trying to access the database from my physical machine Windows  with pgAdmin (ip: 192.168.195.1).

I know I have to make changes in `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` to allow the client to connect, so I had added this:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

in `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf` and

```
host      all              all               192.168.195.95/24            md5
```

in `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf` and I restarted PostgreSQL.

The error information:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on host "192.168.195.95" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Could you please guide me?

Comment: sorry it typing error, i means /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf

Comment: yes i did using /etc/init.d/postgresql restart

Comment: Error saving properties: Unauthorized                                           Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on host "192.168.195.95" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: can you ssh to your virtual machine, `sudo - postgres` and run `psql -c "show listen_addresses"`?..

Comment: plz tell me full command to type

Comment: `ssh 192.168.195.95` to ssh, after login `sudo - postgres` and run `psql -c "show listen_addresses`

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem mentioned above. Please help.